# I tried to use the software updater but it doesn't give the upgrade option

Tags: upgrade

I launched the software updater to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 but the updater doesn't give the upgrade option. The version on the Ubuntu 14.04 shows an upgrade button on the updater.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I run the updater it doesn't detect the new available version. I've also tried running `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it doesn't find the new release. I use the main server in software sources and I've tried other servers as well.

Comment: The only way it seems is to do a `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. For some reason even though the site shows it as available for download now the system still sees it as a Beta release. COME ON UBUNTU! Fix your stuff I say!

Comment: Not even an Ubuntu server system notices it as being out of Beta yet.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I think I'll just wait awhile and see if it gets sorted out!